# Notify ListBox and ListBox Item for CRUD from Background Thread

Tags: sql, wpf, linq, windows-phone-8

I'm working with LINQ/SQL within my WP8 app to manage a collection of items that are shown within a ListBox.
Sometimes one these objects is changed by a long runned operation using another DataContext.
These changes could be one of the CRUD operations, so objects can be created in the background, too.

In iOS there is the NSFetchedResultsController for it or i can use a NSNotification - i'm searching for something similar.

**update** some code for an updating case

I'm fetching my items like this:

```
    void loadData() {
        var items = from r in itemDB.items orderby r.UpdatedAt descending select r;
        var Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(items);
        lstData.ItemsSource = Items;
    }
```

my listBox looks like this

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding LocalState}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>   
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and my background code looks like this:

```
static public void UploadAll() {



        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1,1);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc));

    }

    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo)
    {
        ItemsContext itemsDB = new ItemsContext(ItemsContext.DBConnectionString);

        var notUploadedItems = (from i in itemsDB.items
                                    where !i.LocalState.Equals("server")
                                    select i);

        var Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(notUploadedItems);
        foreach (Item a in Items)
        {
            a.Save(() =>
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                {
                    a.LocalState = "server";
                    itemsDB.SubmitChanges();


                });

                //NOW THE LISTBOX SHOULD BE UPDATED
            }, (err) =>
            {

            });
        }


    }
```

at the `//NOW THE LISTBOX SHOULD BE UPDATED`comment, the corresponding listbox template should be updated

add/delete cases are similar.

cheers.

Comment: post therelevant code and XAML.

Comment: i added some code, thx

Answer (score 0):

To be straight to the point, creating new instance of the `ObservableCollection` every time your data changes then re-assigning it to the `ItemSource`, is not only disregarding core purpose of the `ObservableCollection`, it is also breaking/misusing the concept of `Data
Binding`.

```
//this is the line I am talking about:
var Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(notUploadedItems);
```

Instead, create the `ObserbaleCollection` once -- make it a property:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items {get {return _items;}
```

For the updates use collection's '.Add()' or 'Remove()' methods

You're correct that you must be on the UI Main thread to do the updates:

```
  DoItOnUIThread(() =>Items.Add(newItem));

   //here's a sample of method that would take any action and execute it on UI thread..
   private void DoItOnUIThread(Action action)
    {
        if (_dispatchService == null) 
           _dispatchService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDispatchService>();

        if (_dispatchService.CheckAccess())
            action.Invoke ();
        else
            _dispatchService.Invoke(action);
    }
```

Let the observable collection do its job, which is automatically update the UI through Binding with new items and their property changes. If all that is hooked up/done properly your listbox shouldn't need to be updated in cs code at all.

Comment: thanks, denis. The problem for me is that I do not have any reference to my ObservableCollection when starting my background operation. Assume that all the CRUD changes are happening in another DataContext and not in the same Page class.

Comment: I see, well, you can create an `event` `GotNewData` of type `<Item>`, from your "background operation" after operation completes, raise that event. Listen to that event on the page, then populate your ObservableCollection there

Comment: is there a way to send an event without passing the handler reference?  i know this concept from iOS+Notifications

Comment: yes, check out EventAggregator, it's Prism's, but you can do something similar..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx